# Should we suggest that authors of complete solutions to homework-like questions delete them?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

This week I've seen several complete solutions posted to homework-like questions.

One author asked if he should delete his answer.  I'm inclined to answer yes, he should delete it, but I'm putting the question up here to see what others think.

Ah ... the author deleted it on his own, so I can't link to it.  But my question still stands.

Comment: Yes, you should tell him; you should make him aware that we are not HW solving sites and posting  a full-solution is what is against our HW policy. So, IMO, do tell him.

Comment: FWIW I deleted that post, although the author was offering to delete it if requested to do so, so I think your point stands.

Comment: I'm inclined to say yes, as I frequently flag such answers for deletion

Comment: @user36790 Thanks.  This question is a follow-on to [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7636/5739) that I posted earlier pointing out that guidelines *for providing answers* (not for *asking questions*) are hard to find.  They are buried in the the guidelines for *questions* which is not where one might look for guidance on *answers*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I somewhat regularly mod-flag answers that are complete solutions to (no-effort) homework problems & request deletion. This is in line with what is stated in the [Homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714):

> If someone posts an answer to a homework-type question that gives away a complete or near-complete solution, in most cases it will be temporarily deleted.

So if an *answerer* questions whether they should delete their answer for breaking the policy, then I would say that *Yes, they should be recommended to self-delete* and link them to the relevant policy (q/714 on meta.physics.se) as a reminder as to *why* the policy is as it is.

Comment: This is a good answer.   I only wish that the sentence you highlight were in a post on advice for those providing answers, rather than for those asking questions.   Answerers may not think to look in that link, and even if they do, the advice is buried.   I know I'm repeating myself, but if there are changes on the horizon, perhaps my squeaky wheel might get some grease.

Comment: @garyp: Hmm, I could see the merit in having a *How to answer HW questions* post (I've already upvoted your linked Meta post about it too).